# FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode12

Hi everyone i have some issues with Xcode after updating to the newest version i got this error :

FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've even tried excluded arm64

[image]

Do you have any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Comment: No :( at this time i don't have any solution